# matplotlib FuncAnimation produces black screen when the first passed image is all zeros

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code that plots a sequence of images. It works fine.

```
mask=np.array(np.random.randn(250,512,512))
fig = plt.figure() # make figure
im = plt.imshow(mask[0], cmap=pylab.cm.bone)

# function to update figure
def updatefig(j):
    # set the data in the axesimage object
    im.set_array(mask[j])
    # return the artists set
    return im,
# kick off the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=range(len(mask)), 
                              interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

However, if the initial frame I pass is all zeros than I will only end up with a black image

```
z=np.zeros((1,512,512))
X=np.concatenate((z,mask))

fig = plt.figure() # make figure
im = plt.imshow(X[0], cmap=pylab.cm.bone)

# function to update figure
def updatefig(j):
    # set the data in the axesimage object
    im.set_array(X[j])
    # return the artists set
    return im,
# kick off the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, frames=range(len(X)), 
                              interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Quick idea: try to set `vmin` and `vmax` in `plt.imshow()`. I think the problem is that it tries to guess the value range from the first image, which is zero if the image is all zeros.

Comment: Thank you. that solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(python) matplotlib animation doesn't show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232260/python-matplotlib-animation-doesnt-show)